# Difficulty fetching JSON data in the form of PHP array due to strange OBJECT names in JSON

Tags: php, json, decode, using

I am fetching data from JSON in the form of PHP array.
But I am not able to fetch it due to strange OBJECT titles.

E.g. here is simply example

```
[car] => stdClass Object
    (
        [model] => stdClass Object
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [company] => Honda
                [condition] => Good
            )

    )
```

Now I can fetch "condition" like this $car->model->condition;

But in my case, the JSON is like this

```
[car] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"] => stdClass Object
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [company] => Honda
                [condition] => Good
            )

    )
```

I am not able to fetch "condition" value due to this strange object `[field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"]`

What should I do?

```
$car->[ ?????? ]->condition;
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Was it you that created this JSON ? Or are you getting this from somewhere else

Comment: I am getting this from some other source :(

Comment: Can you please post the original JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `{}` syntax you can address that like this

```
echo $car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'}->condition;
```

> Its ugly and it would really be better if you got the people producing this data to fix their code.

Example

```
$car = new stdClass;
$b = new stdClass;

$b->year = 2018;
$b->company = 'Honda';
$b->condition =  'good';

$car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'} = $b;

print_r($car) . PHP_EOL;

echo 'The condition of the '
        . $car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'}->year . ' '
        . $car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'}->company
        . ' is ' . $car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'}->condition;
```

RESULTS

```
stdClass Object
(
    [field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"] => stdClass Object
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [company] => Honda
            [condition] => good
        )
)

The condition of the 2018 Honda is good
```

Comment: `$car->{'field_set_key="profile",username="sammy"'}->condition;`